# не могу подключиться к jdbc через DriverManager.getConnection

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

Вот мой код:

```
package com.company;

import java.sql.*;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Database {
    public Connection con;

    public Database() {
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
            con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/user?useUnicode=true&serverTimezone=UTC", "root", "");
            System.out.println("Connection success");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public ArrayList<User> getUsers() {
        ArrayList<User> users = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM users");
            ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
            while (rs.next()) {
                Long id = rs.getLong("id");
                String login = rs.getString("login");
                String password = rs.getString("password");
                users.add(new User(id, login, password));
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return users;
    }

    public void AddUser(User user) {
        try {
            PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO users(id, login, password) VALUES(NULL, ?, ?)");
            ps.setString(1, user.getLogin());
            ps.setString(2, user.getPassword());
            System.out.println(ps.executeUpdate()); // rows moved
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void updateLogin(Long id, String log) {
        String s = "UPDATE users SET login = " + log + " WHERE id = " + id;
        try {
            PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(s);
            ps.executeUpdate();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void updatePassword(Long id, String pas) {
        String s = "UPDATE users SET password = " + pas + " WHERE id = " + id;
        try {
            PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(s);
            ps.executeUpdate();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void removeUser(Long id) {
        String s = "DELETE FROM users WHERE id = " + id;

        try {
            PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(s);
            ps.executeUpdate();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Вот такая ошибка:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:129)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:836)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:456)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:246)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:199)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
    at com.company.Database.<init>(Database.java:12)
    at com.company.Main.main(Main.java:6)
```

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужно в MySql утилите предоставить доступ. Исполюзуйте эту команду

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '%ваш пароль%' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```